# Can you reference existing Java classes (POJOs) in a dependent JAR within an OpenAPI schema definition?

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I am using OpenAPI for a new Java service that I have created. I am generating Java code from the OpenAPI spec using openapi-generator-maven-plugin.  A member of the team has thrown me a curve ball and wants to create a new REST endpoint, but use an existing class as opposed to specifying the object via the OpenAPI schemas/components approach.  The [documentation](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/customization.md#bringing-your-own-models) around `importMappings` is not very clear and I have tried this approach, but it does not appear to work.  Does anyone know whether it is possible to use existing POJO classes and if so, do you have a working example that you can share?

```
<importMappings>
  <importMapping>Trade=com.org.project.Trade</importMapping>
</importMappings>
```

The above has been added to the  ...  section of the openapi-generator-maven-plugin definition in the project pom.xml

I then tried to define the schema as follows in my open api json file.

```
TradeWrapper:
      type: object
      properties:
        trade:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/Trade"
```

Comment: Can you post the importMappings configs that you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TradeWrapper:
  type: object
  properties:
    trade:
      $ref: "Trade"
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, but it took two small fixes:

1. pom.xml, in openapi-generator-maven-plugin

```
    <importMappings>
      <schemaMapping>Trade=com.org.project.Trade</schemaMapping>
    </importMappings>
```

2. in openapi.yaml:

```
    TradeWrapper:
      type: object
      properties:
        trade:
          $ref: "#Trade"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).