# Can you reference existing Java classes from spring framework or any library within an OpenAPI schema definition?

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I am trying to do this to implement problemDetail in my spring boot application and in my API docs I want to use org.springframework.http.ProblemDetail to return for statuses 400,401,403,404,500 and doing below in config of open-api-maven-ganerator plugin with 6.6.0 version is not helping

```
<schemaMappings>
            <schemaMapping>ProblemDetail=org.springframework.http.ProblemDetail</schemaMapping>
          </schemaMappings>

ProblemDetailWrapper:
  description: defines the standard error response for failure
  type: object
  properties:
    problemDetail:
      $ref: '#ProblemDetail'
```

> #ProblemDetail is not defined
> Failed to get the schema name: #ProblemDetail
> Error obtaining the datatype from ref: #ProblemDetail. Default to 'object'

And the generated class gives Object type and not **org.springframework.http.ProblemDetail** type

```
public class ProblemDetailWrapper {

  private Object problemDetail = null;

  public ProblemDetailWrapper problemDetail(Object problemDetail) {
    this.problemDetail = problemDetail;
    return this;
  }}
```

[Can you reference existing Java classes (POJOs) in a dependent JAR within an OpenAPI schema definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74552600/can-you-reference-existing-java-classes-pojos-in-a-dependent-jar-within-an-ope)

I have tried this suggestion but it does not work